Running Excel Script to highlighted cells
I am trying to save a script to apply a number format to whatever cells I have selected on the worksheet. Recording the script is easy, but it only applies to whatever cell I am in at the time.  However, I could be in a different cell or I may need to apply the format to a range of cells.
This is a copy of my script at the moment but it is only being applied to cell E8, whereas I want it to run on whatever cells I have selected at the time.
Function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
Set format for range E8 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("E8").setNumberFormatLocal("#,##0;(#,##0);-");
}

I am not sure what I need to replace E8 with to get it to apply to other cells.

There is a method called getSelectedRanges() that allows you to target the selected range. Here is how you can use it in your case:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let selectedRange = selectedSheet.getSelectedRanges();
    for(let range of selectedRange){
        range.setNumberFormatLocal("#,##0;(#,##0);-")
    }
}


Thank you for your reply.  I am still doing something wrong as I have an error message.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
let selectedRange = selectedSheet.getSelectedRanges();
range.setNumberFormatLocal("#,##0;(#,##0);-");
}

It says "see line 3, column 6: office scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable.  Please declare a type for the variable.

@EmmaEmerson You forgot the for(let range of selectedRange){}. The script is: function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) { let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet(); let selectedRange = selectedSheet.getSelectedRanges(); for(let range of selectedRange){range.setNumberFormatLocal("#,##0;(#,##0);-")}} The range variable is set in the for loop :)
